# how to refind the existing session based on the sessionID passed by client in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I am writing my android app using CI as server side.

I use retrofit2 to login (CI generates a session A for this login, some user information will be stored in this session), client will save the cookie locally once it gets the login response and uses it for a webview which will visit the same server.

Now my problem is CI receives correctly the Cookie header in the webview request, but it generates another session B (and the user info stored in session A is not present in session B, so this is completely a new session), while I want to get back to session A, because there is no need to generate another session if there is already one there.

I looked into the CI documentation for session, but I didn't find anything regarding to re-find the session based on the client's cookie, how to accomplish that?

Here are two headers for the login and for show_event (webview load):

For login step,

```
log_message('Functional',"1111111111111111".print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), TRUE));
$headers = $this->input->request_headers();
log_message('Functional',"1111111111111111 login header".print_r($headers, TRUE));
```

Result:

```
FUNCTIONAL - 2016-03-24 18:45:13 --> 1111111111111111Array
(
    [session_id] => 7e4b0249222b2db37b2d7c6b5cf00260
    [ip_address] => 58.49.115.75
    [user_agent] => okhttp/3.1.2
    [last_activity] => 1458816313
    [user_data] => 
    [userinfo] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 23
            [registration] => 999
        )

)

FUNCTIONAL - 2016-03-24 18:45:13 --> 1111111111111111 login headerArray
(
    [Content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
    [Content-length] => 96
    [Host] => www.mydomain.com
    [Connection] => Keep-Alive
    [Accept-encoding] => gzip
    [Cookie] => ci_session=a%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%226b1e425b28105c306ffdfcd3647edd77%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%2258.49.115.75%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22okhttp%2F3.1.2%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1458815597%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22userinfo%22%3Ba%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A7%3A%22user_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2223%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22registration%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22999%22%3B%7D%7Dbee5de8919a1086b48f8b180f41477d2b3af1531
    [User-agent] => okhttp/3.1.2
)
```

For webview display,

```
log_message('Functional',"22222222222222".print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), TRUE));
log_message('Functional',"22222222222222 show_event header".print_r($headers, TRUE));
```

Result:

```
FUNCTIONAL - 2016-03-24 18:45:16 --> 22222222222222Array
(
    [session_id] => 8c5b1d1c1e37fe318a1b64798636115d
    [ip_address] => 58.49.115.75
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, l
    [last_activity] => 1458816316
    [user_data] => 
)

FUNCTIONAL - 2016-03-24 18:45:16 --> 22222222222222 show_event headerArray
(
    [Host] => www.mydomain.com
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [User-agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/40.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
    [Accept-encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Accept-language] => en-US
    [Cookie] => ci_session=a%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%227e4b0249222b2db37b2d7c6b5cf00260%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%2258.49.115.75%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22okhttp%2F3.1.2%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1458816313%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22userinfo%22%3Ba%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A7%3A%22user_id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2223%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%22registration%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22999%22%3B%7D%7D251716da065f66b65228486f25c3445a160e0d8d
    [X-requested-with] => com.mydomain.mydomainandroid
)
```

Maybe CI has a limitation that even we specify the same sessionID but from different user-agent, we can't use the same session?

Comment: Are you sure you have the both cookies?

Comment: @Shomz, sorry, what do you mean?
I have one cookie returned by Retrofit2 (use Okhttp3 behind), and webview send this cookie to CI, CI does receive it.

Comment: I'm thinking your session B cookie overwrites the session A cookie, and that the only fix is to figure out why session B starts, not just to figure out how to access the session A.

Comment: @Shomz, please see the headers for that two requests, I guess I need to do something inside CI to make sure it use always the same session if the two requests have the same sessionID in cookie.